# What Cassandra Driver should I use for Scala?

Tags: scala, cassandra

I am new to cassandra and scala. Please someone provide me an example on how to connect to cassandra database using scala API.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: You should try to find a library which would allow you to establish connection with Cassandra. Then check its documentation to see how it can be used. This question is very broad to answer, as it is.

Comment: please give an example program that will connect to cassandra using scala

Comment: @sravya http://outworkers.com/blog/tag/phantom

Answer (score 2):

Use Phantom DSL.

Check out the Phantom DSL tag on Stack Overflow and the Phantom DSL Git repo:

https://github.com/outworkers/phantom

Check out some examples here:

https://github.com/iamthiago/cassandra-phantom

http://outworkers.com/blog/tag/phantom

I hope this helps,

Rhys